# Allow unauthorized users to access RichFaces Skin CSS files

Tags: authentication, richfaces, skin, jsf-2, appfuse

I've created a small web application using AppFuse(with JSP as Web Framework) and RichFaces. There is a page that uses rich:dataTable that should be accessible without authentication.

To make this page public I put it into a folder called "public" and added the following line to the security.xml:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/public/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
```

The page is now accessible without authentication but the dataTable has no skin as the required CSS files are stored in a folder that apparently requires authentication...

RichFaces Skin CSS files are accessed at this path:

> /a4j/s/3_3_2.SR1org/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_.html

And when I try to access the files I get redirected to the login page.

So how do I allow unauthorized users to access these CSS files?

Thanks, Tom

EDIT: I've already tried adding the line below to security.xml but it didn't work:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/a4j/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem by changing the line from my edit to:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/a4j/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
```

The second ***** does the trick...but I don't know why. :)